# Goroutine deadlock when using a channel with select

Tags: go, select, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I've tried to rewrite a working program which didn't use `select` or `WaitGroup`, so that it would implement `select` and `WaitGroup`, but I've came upon an issue, which I can't find a solution to. It seems that goroutine deadlock occurs, because the `Manager` function is not taking the data from the writer channel, therefore the channel is blocked from sending/receiving and the program locks up.

The original working `Manager` function, without `select` :

```
func Manager(list *[]Request, writerChan <-chan int) {
    ageIn, writersOpen := <-writerChan
    for {
        if writersOpen { // if writers channel is open

            Add(list, Request{Value: ageIn, Count: 1}) // putting new object to list
            ageIn, writersOpen = <-writerChan          // receiving new player from writer channe;

        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**So I had a working program, but needed to implement `WaitGroup` and `select`, there are the updated codes :**

The **updated `Manager` function** with `select` implemenation :

```
func Manager(list *[]Request, writerChan <-chan int) {
    defer waitGroup.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case ageIn := <-writerChan:
            Add(list, Request{Value: ageIn, Count: 1}) // add player to list
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The **updated `Main` function** with `WaitGroup` implementation :

```
var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    list := ParallelList{List: make([]Request, 0)}
    readers, teams, players := ReadData("data.txt")
    writerChan := make(chan int)          //any2one writers channel
    writerFinishChan := make(chan int, 6) // channel to know when all writers are done writing

    waitGroup.Add(6)

    for i := 0; i < len(teams); i++ {
        go Writer(teams, teams[i], writerChan, writerFinishChan)
    }

    go Manager(&list.List, writerChan)
    waitGroup.Wait()
}
```

**The `Writer` function which sends data to writerChan**

```
func Writer(teams [][]Player, team []Player, writerChan chan<- int,
    writerFinishChan chan int) {
    defer waitGroup.Done()
    count := len(team)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        writerChan <- team[i].Age
    }
    writerFinishChan <- 1 // when writer finishes writing, he puts 1 to the "writerFinishChan"

    if len(writerFinishChan) == len(teams) { // if all writers are done writing (the len should be equal to 6)
        close(writerChan)
    }
}
```

So the problem now is that after implementing `select` and `WaitGroup` my program doesn't work properly anymore, it gives me a "fatal error : goroutines asleep, deadlock".

Maybe someone can help me up with sorting out this issue? I'm quite sure that the issue lies within the `Manager` function and it's `select` block

Comment: There is no way to exit the `Manager` for loop. You put a `break` in the default case, but `select` acts the same a `switch` so it is only breaking out of the default case, not the for loop.

Comment: I thought about putting a label for the loop, f.e. `Loop : for { .. } ` and then just put `break Loop` in the default case, but I'm not sure that it is the proper way to fix this issue.

Comment: @Dariuha: while there are still other issues here, breaking from nested blocks is usually easiest if you structure the code to use an early `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your logic to exit the `Manager` func is now different. Before you waited for the channel to be closed, however now you don't check at all. In fact `Manager` will never exit. This also implies that the `WaitGroup` will never be done.

I think the select in `Manager` it not necessary. If you are closing the channel, then just range over it:

```
for ageIn := range writerChan {
  Add(list, Request{Value: ageIn, Count: 1}) // putting new object to list
}
```

This will properly exit when the `writerChan` is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But isn't `select` required to ensure that the program is working concurrently? That is the only reason why I figured I needed to implement `select` block.

Comment: Not quite. The select lets you operate on multiple channels in a single place/go-routine. Go routines are what let you do things concurrently.

Comment: I would still like to figure out how to implement the `select` block in this case. So earlier I checked whether or not the `writerChan` is open, so I would know when to break the loop. What could be condition when using `select`, maybe you have any ideas how I could get it to work?

Comment: Take a look at the go tour on an example of when to use a select: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5. For the select to know if the channel is closed, you would actually do the same thing as you did before: `case ageIn, writersOpen := <- writerChan`

Comment: So in `case ageIn, writersOpen := <- writerChan`, I need an `if` statement `if writersOpen { ... doing my stuff... }` and in `else` of that `if` I should exit the `Manager`, how should that be done? I thought using break should work, but it only exits the `case` and not the `Manager` itself.

Comment: Right, so ranging over the channel is the same as checking the second argument from a channel when reading from it. It is only ever false when the channel is closed. Are you closing the channel anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I do close the channel in a function called `Writer`, I updated the original post with the included code for that function.

Comment: But it never reaches that part where the channel is closed, because the program locks up after 6 writers add 1 of their player to writerChan and that's it. I checked that by printing what is being sent to writerChan. I have 6 teams and every team has some players in it, each writer process is responsible for 1 team and adding that team's players to the writerChan. Program locks up after the first adding of each writer process.

Comment: Probably because your channels have a buffer len of 6. If you made them bigger, would it get to the close?

Comment: Yes. It does close if I make it bigger, but I still get that fatal error about goroutines asleep.

Comment: If thats the case, it implies you are reading and writing from the same go routine. It also implies that you are writing one more than the buffer in the channel can hold, so it will block for ever. That is one problem. Does the panic from the deadlock show where everything is waiting?

Comment: It points to line 31, which is in `main` at `waitGroup.Wait()`

Comment: This implies that some of the Done() methods are not being invoked. Any idea which one? Maybe put some print lines in

Comment: I checked the `Writer` function, it does print out all of the players from the data file and that the channel is closed in the end. So I guess `Writer` function isn't the one. I also checked what `Manager` function takes from the `writerChan`, it takes all the 28 players from that channel. So it shouldn't be the `Manager` either, I have no idea what else to check? However I checked my function called `Add` which is used in the `Writer` function and noticed that I didn't put `defer waitGroup.Done()` there, should I?

Comment: The key is that Done needs to be called the same number of times that you gave WaitGroup.Add(). It doesn't look like your Add should have a Done().

Comment: It seems that I added too many to waitGroup.Add.. I reduced it and now it doesn't show that goroutines are asleep anymore. I didn't know that waitGroup.Add(number) needed the same amount of waitGroup.Done() invokes.. Thank you.

Comment: Good deal! Glad I could help.